# Is possible to have a property on model with no corresponding field on database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I'm using Entity framework , with Database First.

I have created the Model with wizard from an existing database.

Now I have this situation :

Let's suppose that I have a table in database :

> MyTable1 ( ID , Name , Value1 )

Off-course when I create the model with wizard , on the `Model.edmx` , is created an entity with the same structure. But for several reasons during the program executions , on the model only I want to have an extra property that has no corresponding field on database.

So on the model I want something like this :

> MyTable1(ID , Name,Value1, **ExtraValue**)

I need this extra property only for some actions during runtime.

Is possible to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Create `partial` class and annotate property with `NotMappedAttribute`.

While edmx generates code from your datatbase it creates `partial` classes for every table. You can add `partial` class there for your table and then add your property with `NotMapped` attribute.

For example you are having Student table and you want to add Age property that is not in database then you should do something like following.

```
public partial class Student
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int Age{get; set;}
}
```

for more information on NotMappedAttribute visit MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped).

**Update**

for more information on partial classes visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/wa80x488.aspx)

You would also like to visit this link [Extending Entity Framework Generated Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456844(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Entity Framework using Partial classes to add business logic and validation to generated entities](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/)

Comment: All the classes are created automatically during wizard. So should I add manually the extra property to existing class , or should I create a new class ?

Comment: @alex a new partial class.

Comment: But what should I do with my existing partial class ?

Comment: Nothing while compiling compiler will attach both class together in compiled binary.

Comment: Ok , but where should I create this new class , inside the model.edmx or ??? And another question : can this ExtraProperty be used to bound a control ?

Comment: @alex in a seperate c# code file having extension .cs

Comment: thank you , and can this property be used as a normal property , for example can a control be bound to this property ?

Comment: @alex yes of course. That's what your question ask and answer replies.. :)

Comment: @alex I have provided two more links in my answer. I think it would help you to understand and apply.